# Google-Webcomponents - YouTube sign-in fails

Tags: google-web-component

I am trying to implement a YouTube upload feature on my website, I would like to accomplish this using Google's `<google-youtube-upload>` webcomponent.

But when I try to sign in using only a YouTube channel - which also is available as a login option - it says `Object {type: "tokenFailed", idpId: "google", error: "USER_LOGGED_OUT"}` in chrome's console.

It is working just fine if I log in using a Google+ account that has a YouTube channel of the same name associated to it.

Is it not possible to authorize using only a YouTube channel? Or am I simply missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since this was a school project and I've spent too much time on researching and trying to fix this problem without luck, rather than making actual progress I've decided to just let it be and strike this feature.